# Can we receive the voice command converted as a string in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

Can we receive the voice command converted as a string in Android Wear? Or do we get the array of microphone amplitude values?

Comment: I got the answer for this: the Android Wear system delivers your app on the handheld the message as a string extra in the Intent you specified to be used for the action.
http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/remote-input.html

<br/>
I do not want to delete this post because in the near future, it might be useful for others. :)

Comment: Have you find a solution for your issue? If yes can you help me by writing a code snippet from the `ReplyActivity.class`? Thank you

Comment: lucgian841: yes, I got the answer for my query which I have already posted in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Wear system delivers your app on the handheld the message as a string extra in the Intent you specified to be used for the action.

This link is very useful: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/remote-input.html) 
Also, the link posted by @beworker: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEZbZK4jFLY)

I am answering to my question as it might be useful for others in the near future. Because, now we are entering the era of wearable computing! :)

Answer (score 3):

You will get an extra `reply` string with the reply intent. Here is a [nice short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEZbZK4jFLY) explaining this.

Comment: I tried to follow the video but I don't understand what I've to do in the `ReplyActivity.class`... Can you help me to understand?

Comment: @lucgian841, Can you please specify what you don't understand in ReplyActivity class?

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the ElizaChat sample which does that